# Visual Studio Premium 2013, .Net 4.5; no Blank App (XAML) option under Visual C# Store Apps

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2013

Following a very specific C# book that is telling me to go to File -> New Project -> Visual C#, Windows Store, and select Blank App (XAML). There is no Blank App (XAML) option. 
Am I just supposed to use Blank App (Universal Apps)? 
Want to make sure before I get knee deep in an app only to find out it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Did you open the Store Apps node?  If you look at the attached picture it shows that if you expand the Store Apps (formally Windows Store), it has three nodes.  Universal, Windows Apps and Windows Phone...just select Windows Apps and you will see the Blank App (Windows) template that you are looking for.  It is no longer called Blank App (XAML).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

go on your vs2013, create an new project:
 File -> New project -> Installed -> Templates -> Visual C# -> Windows Desktop  then choose WPF Application template.